# how to solve Exception has occurred problem in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

when i run this code :

```
     body: Center(
        child: Image(
          image: NetworkImage(
              'https://images.pexels.com/photos/4431905/pexels-photo-4431905.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500'),
        ),
        // child: Text(
```

app is not debugging its says

**Exception has occurred.
_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart': Failed assertion: line 238 pos 12: '_completer == null': is not true.)**

```
  void setCompleter(ImageStreamCompleter value) {
    assert(_completer == null);
    _completer = value;
    if (_listeners != null) {
      final List<ImageStreamListener> initialListeners = _listeners;
      _listeners = null;
      initialListeners.forEach(_completer.addListener);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you show us more of your code because i just run your code and it seems that it works

Comment: when i try another link it works thank you for listening

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you try some other link? It could be that the completer is not getting the image in the end.